# Не запускается TCPServer при использовании его в службе

Tags: delphi

Хочу создать службу для текстового чата, после установки самой службы и ее запуска, ничего не происходит, не запускается IdTCPServer

```
unit Main_Unit;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.SvcMgr, Vcl.Dialogs, IdBaseComponent,
  IdComponent, IdCustomTCPServer, IdTCPServer, INIFiles, IdGlobal, FileCtrl,
  IdContext,WinSock;

type TConnectedUsers = record
  Nickname: array of string;
  IP: array of string;
  FreePlace: array of boolean;
end;

type
  TTCP_Chat_Service = class(TService)
    IdTCPServer1: TIdTCPServer;
    procedure ServiceBeforeInstall(Sender: TService);
    procedure ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
    procedure ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    function GetServiceController: TServiceController; override;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  TCP_Chat_Service: TTCP_Chat_Service;
  LogDir: string;
  LogFile: TextFile;
  port: Word;
  ConnectedUsers:TConnectedUsers;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure AddLog(var add: string);
begin
  AssignFile(logfile, LogDir + '\[' + DateToStr(Now) + '].txt');
  if FileExists(LogDir) then
    Append(logfile)
  else
    Rewrite(logfile);
  Writeln(logfile, add);
  CloseFile(logfile);
end;


procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  TCP_Chat_Service.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TTCP_Chat_Service.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TTCP_Chat_Service.ServiceBeforeInstall(Sender: TService);
var OptionsINI: TINIFile;
    Count:integer;
begin
  OptionsINI:=TIniFile.Create(extractfilepath(paramstr(0))+'Options.ini');
  Port:=OptionsINI.ReadInteger('Options','Port',Port);
  Count:=OptionsINI.ReadInteger('Options','Count_of_users',Count);
  SetLength(ConnectedUsers.Nickname,Count);
  SetLength(ConnectedUsers.IP,Count);
  SetLength(ConnectedUsers.FreePlace,Count);
  if SelectDirectory(LogDir, [sdAllowCreate], 0) then
    if not DirectoryExists(LogDir) then
      ForceDirectories(LogDir);
end;

procedure TTCP_Chat_Service.ServiceStart(Sender: TService;
  var Started: Boolean);
var add:string;
begin
  IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort:=Port;
  IdTCPServer1.Active := True;
  Started:=true;
end;

procedure TTCP_Chat_Service.ServiceStop(Sender: TService; var Stopped: Boolean);
begin
  IdTCPServer1.Active:=false;
  Stopped:=true;
end;

end.
```

Не могу понять что происходит, потому что не так давно начал изучать создание служб под Delphi

Comment: Не заметил в вашем коде ни единого Try =) для службы это более критично чем для приложения. Ведите лог ошибок и смотрите что у вас происходит

Comment: Собственно, ничего не происходит, потому что происходить нЕчему. Считайте, что ServiceBeforeInstall и ServiceStart происходят с разными процессами. И для того, в котором вызывается Start, естественно, никакие переменные а-ля port не инициализированы